# Envers doesn't do anything

Tags: jpa, entity, hibernate-envers

I was very happy, because from the documentation it seemed to be very easy to setup Envers.

I set up dependecies with gradle, put @Audited annotation to my Driver entity, made driver_aud and revinfo tables.

I'm using these libraries:

```
    hibernateEm           : 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.11.Final',
    hibernateCore         : 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.11.Final',
    hibernateEnvers       : 'org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:4.3.11.Final'
```

But when I make a change on my drivers, nothing happens, no error messages, no audit records.

With a different persistence unit to a test database, the audit table and revinfo table were automatically generated, so Envers is partly working, but doesn't make audit records.

Comment: Could you post the code where you're creating and saving or updating your entity?

Comment: I only persist it with entityManager.persist and updating with only changing the entity. Is it not enough?  em.persist(driver);      driver.setFirstName(firstName);

Comment: Driver entity extends an abstract BaseEntity with @MappedSuperclass annotation, maybe this is the cause of my problem.

Comment: I'm using JTA as persistence unit transaction type.

Comment: Both environments are using JTA environments?  If so, it sounds like the `beforeTransactionCompletion()` callbacks aren't being fired for some reason.  How are you setting up your JTA things?

Comment: No, the application persistence unit is using JTA, the other is using RESOURCE_LOCAL transaction type. The only place where I am setting up JTA is the persistence.xml. Maybe I trying to find out what else should I configure with JTA to get Envers to work.

Comment: I haven't been made aware of any JTA issues with Envers.  Would you be able to log a JIRA with a JTA example for me to check?

Comment: What is the address of your JIRA? I found this, but I can't reach it: *** MOVED *** To Hibernate JIRA: http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH (component: envers)

Comment: https://hibernate.atlassian.net - and component is hibernate-envers

Comment: After I forked hibernate-test-case-templates project from github, I tried to make a simple sample to show my problem with envers and JTA. Because of the JTA I need to run the test within a container, so now I'm trying to use Arquillian. Right now I'm having problems with it, so it's not ready yet. As soon as it is done, I will make a JIRA ticket and you can check it.

Comment: With Wildfly Embedded and Arquillian I cannot reproduce the problem. (https://github.com/szilagyif/envers-jta-test) Revinfo and _aud tables are updated when it's necessary. I don't know how can I solve this, it seems it is not an Envers bug, so I won't make JIRA for you. There is something wrong with our application or configuration, but I can't find it.

Comment: Can you post relevant code / configurations so we can help?